# Angular 12 Build Issue - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular, angular12

Getting below build error after angular upgrade to 12.

**FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

[image]

I have increased the --max_old_space_size to 8192 but still getting the same issue while building

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the Node Sass version, when you upgrade angular you need to upgrade the Node Js as well which eventually requires to upgrade Node Sass package one that is used

You can find the proper mapping following this link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass